# Drawing a colored rectangle in a grayscale video using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Here is my code
I need to draw a color line and rectangle on my gray video stream.
In my code some bug because my line and rectangle are black but they are not.

```
import cv2 
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
    print("Unable to read camera feed")

frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame_width,frame_height),0)

while(cap.isOpened()): 
    
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # draw line
    start_point = (0, 0)
    end_point = (250, 250)
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    thickness = 5
    gray = cv2.line(img=gray, pt1=start_point, pt2=end_point, color=color, thickness=thickness, lineType=8, shift=0)
    
    # draw rectangle
    x1,y1 = 200, 200
    x2,y2 = 250, 250  
    gray = cv2.rectangle(gray,(x1, y1), (x2, y2),color, 2)
    
    cv2.imshow('webcam(1)', gray)

    out.write(gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break
  

cap.release() 
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: to draw color elements you have to convert image back to `BGR` with `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw color elements you have to convert image back to `BGR`

```
 gray_BGR = cv2.cvtColor(gray cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Converting to GRAY not only converts colors to gray but it also reduces every pixel from three values (B,G,R) to single value which can keep only gray color.

If you check `frame.shape` and `gray.shape` then you see difference.
First will have `(height, width, 3)` second will have only `(height, width)` which means `(height, width, 1)`